# How to create a binary STL file containing more than one solid?

Tags: binaryfiles, stl-format

Including more than one solid in an ASCII STL file has been well described.

```
solid name1
    facet normal N.x N.y N.z
        outer loop
            vertex V1.x V1.y V1.z
            vertex V2.x V2.y V2.z
            vertex V3.x V3.y V3.z
        endloop
    endfacet
    facet …
        …
    endfacet
    …
endsolid name1
solid name2
    …
endsolid name2
…
```

However, the format described for a binary STL file does not say anything about including multiple solid objects.

```
       80 Bytes  string   Header
        4 Bytes  uint32   Facets count

      | 4 Bytes  float    N.x
      | 4 Bytes  float    N.y
      | 4 Bytes  float    N.z
      | 4 Bytes  float    V1.x
      | 4 Bytes  float    V1.y
      | 4 Bytes  float    V1.z
facet1| 4 Bytes  float    V2.x
      | 4 Bytes  float    V2.y
      | 4 Bytes  float    V2.z
      | 4 Bytes  float    V3.x
      | 4 Bytes  float    V3.y
      | 4 Bytes  float    V3.z
      | 2 Bytes  uint16   Attrib

facet2| …

facet3| …

…
```

Comment: What's the meaning of a solid in STLs anyways? Isn't it just triangles? And how you arrange them is up to you. So just arrange them such that they form to solid bodies.

Comment: This might not be the case if you have your binary STL file read by other applications. My intention is to generate an STL file containing multiple solid objects as different boundaries of the model and import it in ANSYS Fluent / ICEM CFD software.

Comment: Here, `solid` just means a part.

Comment: @ChristianFritz different solid might mean also different material or head while printing.

Comment: @Spektre yes, that may be what the user desires. But STL is not expressive enough to represent that, is it?

Comment: @ChristianFritz unlike ASCII binary STL does not have the solid clause defining solids so the attr is the only way to specify this. the ASCII is expensive to load/save, the binary is ~1000x times faster which is for very big exports crucial ... it is a difference if you are loading 3 seconds or 45 min ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the binary format each facet has got an attribute (`attrib`). The facets whose `attrib` are the same will be considered part of the same solid.